# How to select row by distinct column and max datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.9, django-3.0

Trying to get the last records I inserted in database based on `DateTime` and distinct column `SocialMedia_ID` but I get the following error `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` when it reaches to the below line:

```
accountsTwitter = StatsTwitter.objects.all().order_by('DateTime').distinct('SocialMedia_id')
```

I want to mention that below SQL query is working, and I need to convert it to django.

```
SELECT *  FROM stats_Twitter WHERE DateTime IN (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM stats_Twitter GROUP BY SocialMedia_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last records

```
last_record = StatsTwitter.objects.last()
```

if you want last n records then

```
last_n_records = StatsTwitter.objects.all().order_by('-DateTime')[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your `SozialMedia` model looks like, but I assume you have one. If that's the case than this is the way to go:

```py
accounts_twitter = SocialMedia.objects.annotate(last_stat=Max('StatsTwitter__Datetime'))
```

I have not tested it but this should work. please also use that I would not recommend naming a field `DateTime` because this could lead to conflicts with `datetime.datetime`